# Modify EcoResProductCreate form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have created a new field to insert via the `EcoResProductCreate` form, the problem is, the value is not saved in the EcoResProduct table. The field exists on the `EcoResProduct` table.

Therefore I think i have to modify the method:

```
saveControlValuesToProduct
```

I have added the line:

```
ecoResProduct.NewField = NewField.text();
```

I am receiving the error:

```
Variable NewField has not been declared.
```

Where do I declare this variable, if i compare it to other existing fields, It seems it is all the same.

What are the actions I have to take to make sure the field is being inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set property `AutoDeclaration` to **Yes** on your form control `NewField`

[image]